# Terminology for "reversible" binary function

Tags: functions, terminology, binary-operations

What is the terminology for a "reversible" binary function, such that of we can compute the result from two operands, that is $f(x,y) = z$, then we can also compute one operand from the result and the other operand, that is $g(x,z) = y$?

For example, with addition if we know $x + y = z$ we can compute $x = z - y$, but we can't do the same for $\min(x,y)=z$. The context of this in terms of Fenwick trees and range queries: we can compute prefix sums for $\min$, but not arbitrary range queries like sums where $\sum a[l,r] = p[r] - p[l-1]$, ($p$ is the prefix sums).

In terms of algebra, I think this is maybe not a property of the binary function but the existence of inverses. For an associative operation, $x * y = z$ lets us compute $x * y * y^{-1} = z * y^{-1}$ if $y^{-1}$ exists.

Comment: Well, your English statement and your functional version are a bit confused. For example, multiplication on $\mathbb N^+$ has your English property, but the domain of $g$ is unclear. It would have to be all pairs $(m,n)$ with $m \mid n.$ Would you want $g$ defined for all $x,z?$

Comment: In general, this seems like you want left-cancellative. But your wording is vague enough, that it isn’t clear. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cancellation_property?wprov=sfti1

Comment: The article I read originally wrote in terms of a secondary "reverse" function $g$, with something like for all $x,y,z$, $f(x,y)=z \implies g(x,z)=y$, but I suspect this can be formulated in terms of inverse elements instead of a pair of functions like $(+,-)$ or $(\times, /)$. Looking at subtraction, $-$ is just $+$ on an inverse element.

Comment: That was not my complaint. It would be worth including the actual text from the article.

Comment: The actual article which I was looking for better terminology on https://cp-algorithms.com/data_structures/fenwick.html